# Add dependency between 2 Dofn in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is there any way I can create dependency between 2 Dofn, so that it will wait for 1st Dofn method to complete then second Dofn method will run. 
Just wondering how we can achieve this use-case.

Comment: What do you mean by "complete?"

Comment: I meant 2nd dofn should wait until the completion of 1st Dofn.

Comment: By "completion" you mean run over all the elements before the 2nd runs over any of them? If so, the answer below is good.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a cleaner way to do this, but I've noticed that doing the following will acheive the effect you desire:

Route the output of the first DoFn to also go to a counter, and then have the output of that counter be passed into the ParDo of the second DoFn as a side input

```
class DoFn2(apache_beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, count_do_fn_1_output, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...

do_fn_1_output = do_fn_1_input | 'do fn 1' >> apache_beam.ParDo(DoFn1())

count_do_fn_1_output = (
    do_fn_1_output 
    | 'count do_fn_1_output' >> apache_beam.combiners.Count.Globally())

do_fn_2_output = (
    do_fn_1_output 
    | 'do fn 2' >> apache_beam.ParDo(DoFn2(), count_do_fn_1_output=apache_beam.pvalue.AsSingleton(count_do_fn_1_output)))
```

Comment: Another option is to insert a beam.util.Reshuffle() between the two DoFns.

Comment: If your Dofn output is of huge size , then it doesn't make sense to send this result as a side-input, it might hamper your overall pipeline performance.

Comment: The side input is the count of the output, not the arraybof the entire pcollection. Waiting for dofn1 in general is hampering your performance

Comment: You could even "process" your PCollection with a `beam.FlatMap(lambda x: None)` that never emits anything and use that as a side input as well.

Answer (score 0):

For Java SDK I'd recommend to take a look on `Wait` transform. [This is an example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/1856d8533c879ab236d0593be1f9c7fff41edd7f/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.java#L53) similar to what you want to achieve as I can guess.